# Vue dynamic image change onmouseover doesn't work

Tags: vue.js

in my vue app i have this image working fine:

```
<img src="@/assets/images/icon-filter-up.png">
```

but when i try to pass the value dinamically like so:

```
<img :src="imgLink">
```

and `imgLink` under `data()` is as follows:

```
imgLink: "@/assets/images/icon-filter-up.png"
```

the image is not found, any idea why is that? i thought it has something to do with using the `@` sign but even when changing it to as many `../../../` as needed it still didn't work

Comment: Could you share more codes or, a working demo code in JsFiddle or else?

Comment: Given the question, I'm guessing you are using webpack or something similar, if so add a tag for that since it's likely the interaction with that tool that is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use the `require` function to get the url of your asset:

```
imgLink: require('@/assets/images/icon-filter-up.png')
```

Comment: Thank you for validating my answer. Note that @lmarqs's one should also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can import a image and use it as a component attribute:

```
<template>
    <img :src="imgLink">
</template>
<script>
    import imgLink from '@/assets/images/icon-filter-up.png';

    export default {
        data: { imgLink }
    };
</script>
```